# jQuery: display overlay over elements on hover using mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery, overlay, mouseenter, mouseleave

To do this I wrote a script that works fine but only for slow motions of mouse, whenever it goes fast it becomes buggy, what can I improve in this script? Any recommandation?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.random = function() {return Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,17))}

    $.fn.addOverlay = function() {
        $("<div class='overlay'></div>")
                .css({'position': 'absolute', 'background-color': '#9fc4e7', 'opacity': 0.3, 'top': $(this).offset().top, 'left': $(this).offset().left, 'width': $(this).width(), 'height': $(this).height()})
                .attr('overlayId',overlayId)
                .appendTo('body')
                .mouseleave(function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                    $('.overlay').each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('overlayId')==overlayId) {
                            $(this).remove()
                        }
                    })
                });
        return this
    }

    $('div:not(.overlay),span,h1,h2,h3,h4,table,td,tr,p')
        .mouseenter(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            overlayId = Math.random();
            $(this).addOverlay()
            .find('div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,table,td,tr,p').each(function(){
                $(this).addOverlay(overlayId)
            })
        })

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the way to do it right, I put it here for anyone who land here ;)
(you can injecte the script in this page to try it ;-))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.random = function() {return Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,17))}
        $.z_index = 1;
        $.data_ = Array();

        $.fn.addOverlay = function(id) {
            $("<div class='overlay' id='"+id+"'></div>")
                    .css({'z-index': $.z_index, 'position': 'absolute', 'background-color': '#9fc4e7', 'opacity': 0.1, 'border': '2px solid black', 'top': $(this).offset().top, 'left': $(this).offset().left, 'width': $(this).outerWidth(), 'height': $(this).outerHeight()})
                    .appendTo('body');
            $.z_index = $.z_index+1;
            return this
        }

        $('div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,table,td,tr,a,ul,li,ol,input,textarea,p,code,img').each(function(){
            rand = $.random();
            $(this).attr('DOMId',rand);
            $.data_.push(Array(
                rand,
                {'x': $(this).offset().left,                        'y': $(this).offset().top},
                {'x': $(this).offset().left+$(this).outerWidth(),   'y': $(this).offset().top},
                {'x': $(this).offset().left+$(this).outerWidth(),   'y': $(this).offset().top+$(this).outerHeight()},
                {'x': $(this).offset().left,                        'y': $(this).offset().top+$(this).outerHeight()},
                false
            ))
        });

        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            for (i in $.data_) {
                x = e.pageX;
                y = e.pageY;
                if((x>$.data_[i][1].x) & (x<$.data_[i][2].x) & (y>$.data_[i][1].y) & (y<$.data_[i][3].y) & (!$.data_[i][5]))  {
                    $('[DOMId="'+$.data_[i][0]+'"]').addOverlay($.data_[i][0]);
                    $.data_[i][5] = true;
                } else if(((x<$.data_[i][1].x) | (x>$.data_[i][2].x) | (y<$.data_[i][1].y) | (y>$.data_[i][3].y)) & ($.data_[i][5])) {
                    $('#'+$.data_[i][0]).remove();
                    $.data_[i][5] = false;  
                }
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: This is really cool.. similar to chrome console's element browser.  May I ask what you're using this script for exactly?

Comment: Yes of course, in fact this is exactly what I was looking for: do the same thing as chrome dev tools, in order to select some elements that will be passed (via their attributes) to a perl script for a scraping purpos

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$(element).hover(function(){
    //on mouse enter 
},function(){ 
    // on mouse leave
});
```

Comment: Thank you tpaksu, I already tried this, it gives the same issue

Comment: tell me what you want to do. it looks a bit confusing.

Comment: Okey, it looks like what the chrome developer tool does when we hover a node in the "Elements" tab, an overlay appears over the current element, I want the same thing but whent the mouse hover the element itself (not the node in the "Elements" tab)

Comment: Ok but when the mouse is over the overlay what will you do? to get focus on the inner elements will be hard. Maybe you can use the element's border style instead of an overlay.

Comment: I prefer not to alter the element style when hovering.
What I want now is an overlay that appears when hovering an element, and disapear when the mouse leave the element, I guess if chrome does it I can too.

Comment: but chrome does it with a dom list :) I mean when the mouse is over the first container element, the inner elements would be inaccessible because of the overlay. your mouse events will not fire because it'll always be on the overlay.

Comment: Yes I know, but if you look at my script, I make it create overlays for all children in a given element ;) and when the mouse is over an overlay of a children the overlay of the parent will disapear... As I said it works when motions are slow, there must be an improvement..

Comment: ok let me test it myself. btw, you look at the "pointer-events:none;" css attribute to bypass the overlay mouse capture.

Comment: thanks, this CSS property looks useful if ever my script doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like working on chrome. I'll test on other browsers now.

```
$("body").append("<div id='test-overlay'></div>");
    $("#test-overlay")
                .css("opacity",0.5)
                .css("background","blue")
                .css("pointer-events","none")
                .css("position","absolute")
                .hide();

    $("h1,h2,h3,div,body,span,a,img,section,header,footer").hover(function(){
        $("#test-overlay")
            .css("left",$(this).offset().left)
            .css("top",$(this).offset().top)
            .width($(this).outerWidth())
            .height($(this).outerHeight())
            .show();
    },function(){

        $("#test-overlay")
            .hide();


    });
```

Comment: IE9 seems not accepting the "pointer-events: none" css and because of it its not working ok.

Comment: Applied to this body

`<div>


Hello I'm the parent div

 <div>

  Hello I'm a 1st generation child

 </div>

 <div>

  Hello I'm a 1st generation child

  <div>

   hello I'm a 2nd child generation

  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<span id="me">here is another div</span>

`
It still buggy ;)

Comment: Firefox is working good too. And appending to body is what chrome, opera does all the time. I didn't inspect them on other browsers but they are all doing it too I guess.

Comment: Yes, but still less buggy then mine ;) thanks I'll follow this way.
Note that it is also less buggy on FF than Chrome

Comment: try replacing the outer's with inner's.

Comment: replacing outer by inner changed nothing, what I remarked is that when I pass from a child div to a parent div the overlay doesn't appear, and also when a pass from tr to td

Comment: hovering a td works on FF but not on Chrome.
passing from a child div (e.g.) do it's parent dont work.